# Display the environmental variables seen by desktop applications

Tags: linux, desktop, environment-variables

How can I know what environmental variables will be set when a desktop application (not bash or other command line shells) launches? Is there a utility tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look in the `/proc` filesystem, e.g. `/proc/1234/environ`.

Comment: It's really a good answer, but one should now that the elements are  separated by standard zeroes. Thus a looking requires something like: cat /proc/5369/environ | tr "\0" "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with this content, I'll call it /tmp/env.awk:

$> cat /tmp/env.awk

```
BEGIN {
   for ( var in ENVIRON)
      printf "%s = \"%s\"\n", var, ENVIRON[var] > "/tmp/env.lst"
}
```

Then create a desktop/menu icon in your favourite window manager whose command line is:

```
awk -f /tmp/env.awk
```

After activating that icon's "app", you will see the the environment in /tmp/env.lst. It's the basic env all starting apps see by default, however their starters may customize it according their needs.